# jquery ui tabs and php echo out the data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I am using [jquery ui's tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

And i want to make it dynamic by getting the tabs from a mysql database using php , but not sure how to add the fragment 1 , 2 , 3 according to the number of rows of the table i have.
For example , there's 5 rows , that means there's 5 fragment. here's the html code for the jquery ui.

```
<div id="featured" >
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img class="thumb" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0f/Avs38.jpg/250px-Avs38.jpg" alt="" /><span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span></a></li>
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img class="thumb" src="http://www.crunchbase.com/assets/images/original/0007/5132/75132v1.jpg" alt="" /><span>20 Beautiful Long Exposure Photographs</span></a></li>  
    </ul>
    <!-- First Content -->
    <div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="info" >
        <h2><a href="#" >Loerm Ipsum</a></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Normally i would use this php code to echo out database

```
  <?php
           $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )){

      $rows[] = $row;

      echo "'Some html code data $row[image] test'\n";
      }

    }

    ?>
```

However if i use this code , it will generate a html like :

```
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Loerm Ipsum</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Loerm Ipsum2</a></h2>
            <p>L2222<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
            </div>
</div>
```

As you can see , it does not make the second fragment , fragment TWO.

I want the results to be like this:

```
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Loerm Ipsum</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tincidunt condimentum lacus. Pellentesque ut diam....<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="info" >
            <h2><a href="#" >Loerm Ipsum2</a></h2>
            <p>L2222<a href="#" >read more</a></p>
            </div>
</div>
```

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about initial loading of the tabs, then modify your code to have a counter, and output the value of that counter to the tab fragment as follows:

```
<?php
    $count = 0; // Initialize counter
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
        $rows[] = $row;
        echo '<div id="fragment-' . ++$count . '" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">';
        echo "'Some html code data $row[image] test'\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $rows = array();
    $frag = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )){

       $rows[] = $row;
       echo "fragment-$frag";
       echo "'Some html code data $row[image] test'\n";
       $frag++;
  }

}

?>
```